How to enable NAT loopback/hairpinning with iptables on router?
I have a HG659b router, and have got shell access to the router, so I can configure the iptables.
In the web page, I have configure a port forwarding setup to forward port 37777 to the host 192.168.1.254. This is all working fine from the WAN with a dynamic DNS but when I try to connect from the LAN with WAN domain name, it doesn't work, the connection times out.
I have done some research and believe this may be because of NAT loopback, not supported by the router. But I was wondering if I could configure this with iptables. Or is there any other alternatives.
Output of ifconfig:
ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fd3c:678c:859a:a500::1/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6466 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1812772 (1.7 MiB)  TX bytes:2537236 (2.4 MiB)

br1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B6:7A:E7:05:81:C7  
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b47a:e7ff:fe05:81c7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:696 (696.0 B)

dsf0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Base address:0xda00 

eth0.2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:84 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2314 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7999 (7.8 KiB)  TX bytes:514134 (502.0 KiB)
          

eth0.3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5067 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4906 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:703538 (687.0 KiB)  TX bytes:1864475 (1.7 MiB)
          

eth0.4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:220 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2483 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37065 (36.1 KiB)  TX bytes:543870 (531.1 KiB)
          

eth0.5    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2090 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3031 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:616219 (601.7 KiB)  TX bytes:893972 (873.0 KiB)
          

imq0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

imq1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

imq2      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

imq3      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

imq4      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16000  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:11000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:716 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:136815 (133.6 KiB)  TX bytes:136815 (133.6 KiB)

nas0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          

nas0_e_oam Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e67:8cff:fe85:9aa5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

nas_p1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A7  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e67:8cff:fe85:9aa7/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:44195 (43.1 KiB)  TX bytes:79646 (77.7 KiB)

nas_p1_1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A6  
          inet addr:<public ip>  Bcast:159.196.19.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e67:8cff:fe85:9aa6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING ALLMULTI MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:147 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:188 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:42137 (41.1 KiB)  TX bytes:79592 (77.7 KiB)

nas_p_oam Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:A5  
          inet6 addr: fe80::3e67:8cff:fe85:9aa5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:702 (702.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wl0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:AC  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3862 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:1308
          TX packets:4351 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:714714 (697.9 KiB)  TX bytes:1157307 (1.1 MiB)
          Interrupt:15 Base address:0x4000 

wl1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 3C:67:8C:85:9A:B0  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:996
          TX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:15114 (14.7 KiB)  TX bytes:48105 (46.9 KiB)
          Interrupt:48 

Output of iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4304 packets, 655K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:50000:50020 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:0 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:6050 
 5222  620K INPUT_BRIDGE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5312  645K PRE_HIGH_PRIO  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5253  642K PRE_IPSEC_DNAT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5246  641K PRE_IPSEC_ACCEPT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 5156  616K PRE_SERVICE_ACL  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 3609  529K PRE_DONAT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 3594  527K PRE_UPNP   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 3594  527K PRE_FTP    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 3594  527K PRE_SERVICE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 3594  527K PRE_PORT_TRIGGER  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 3541  509K PREROUTING_DMZ  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           LOG flags 0 level 1 prefix `Smurf attack -> ' 
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2915  369K PRE_UPNP   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 75 packets, 9826 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1108  164K POSTROUTING_IPSEC  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1108  164K POSTROUTING_MULTINAT  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1038  155K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      nas_p1_1  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 497 packets, 38928 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_BRIDGE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  br1    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.1         
 1831  146K RETURN     all  --  br0    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.1         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.1.1         
    5   375 DROP       all  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            192.168.2.1         

Chain POSTROUTING_IPSEC (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING_MULTINAT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PREROUTING_DMZ (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_DONAT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:37777 to:192.168.1.254:37777 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:10000 to:192.168.1.72:10000 
    0     0 ACCEPT     2    --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain PRE_FTP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_HIGH_PRIO (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_IPSEC_ACCEPT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_IPSEC_DNAT (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_PORT_TRIGGER (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain PRE_SERVICE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpts:67:68 
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:500 
    0     0 ACCEPT     esp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.0/4         

Chain PRE_SERVICE_ACL (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:631 
  224 13416 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 37215,37443 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 137,138,139,445 
    3   428 ACCEPT     udp  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 137,138,139,445 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 21,990 
  363 38028 ACCEPT     icmp --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1047 60137 ACCEPT     tcp  --  br+    *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 80,443 
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  nas_p1_1 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8081 

Chain PRE_UPNP (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080 to:192.168.1.251:80 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:37777 to:192.168.1.251:37777 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:37778 to:192.168.1.251:37778 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:554 to:192.168.1.251:554 
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:18877 to:192.168.1.251:18877 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5060 to:192.168.1.251:5060 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15001 to:192.168.1.251:15001 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15002 to:192.168.1.251:15002 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15003 to:192.168.1.251:15003 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15004 to:192.168.1.251:15004 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15005 to:192.168.1.251:15005 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15006 to:192.168.1.251:15006 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15007 to:192.168.1.251:15007 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15008 to:192.168.1.251:15008 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15009 to:192.168.1.251:15009 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15010 to:192.168.1.251:15010 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15012 to:192.168.1.251:15012 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15011 to:192.168.1.251:15011 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15013 to:192.168.1.251:15013 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15014 to:192.168.1.251:15014 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15015 to:192.168.1.251:15015 
    0     0 DNAT       udp  --  !br+   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:15016 to:192.168.1.251:15016 

If you need any more information on my router setup, please let me know.
Any help or commands to test out would be appreciated.
Thanks,
jpac14
